# Why using Dispose as a normal method is bad?

Tags: c#, language-lawyer, dispose

Trying to figure it out. Someone told me

> Dispose is **not** just a method - it's equivalent to a destructor in other languages.

Ok. [Msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose.aspx) is also very loud about this.

But then

```
class Test : IDisposable
{
    public string Property { get; set; } = "Test";
    public void Dispose() => Console.WriteLine("Disposed, very scary");
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var test = new Test();
        test.Dispose();
        test.Property = "123";  // but it's disposed OMG! do not do this!
        test.Dispose();

        using (var another = new Test())
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                another.Dispose();
                GC.Collect(); // or what should I call to make it crash?
            }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

And there are no problems.

What I think about `Dispose`:

- it's a normal public method;
- `IDisposable` is useful in conjunction with `using` to automatically call `Dispose`, nothing more;
- it's totally fine to put into dispose any code an call it internally at any time if object state properly maintained.

Correct me if I am wrong.

P.S: Downvote means "question is bad/not useful/has problem". If you simply disagree with my thoughts - post comment or answer. It will be useful for people who think as I do right now (because I am wrong? then prove it)

Comment: By the gods, the lambda method declarations are here. Make it stop :(

Comment: @Gusdor, it's `C# 6.0` times. Accept it!

Comment: your code should throw an exception when you operate on the disposed object, there is only no problem because it doesn't do so

Comment: @thumbmunkeys, that's the point. Care to explain that in the answer? I don't see the problem in not detecting.

Comment: *Dispose is not just a method - it's equivalent to a destructor in other languages*, I'd say a finalizer is the closest to a destructor.

Comment: IDisposable is a contract, its up to the developer to actually dispose the object graph or remove which ever type of object that needs disposing. Yes you can put any code in the dispose method, but its a terrible idea not to to what the contract wants you to do. Coding by Convention

Comment: .NET does not have a deterministic destructor like other languages, saying that something in .NET is the closest thing to a deterministic destructor is usually a bad thing, trying to fit a square peg into a round hole. .NET has different concepts, it's much better to learn how they work instead of clinging to concepts from other languages/frameworks.

Comment: Dispose is just a method. There's nothing special about it. What's special is the treatment an `IDisposable` object itself gets, i.e., it won't be eligible to be garbage collected until its dispose is called. In your example `another` can't be garbage collected automatically because it still has references to it which are still in scope.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Dispose` is just a method, you can call it just like any other method. It is always exposed through the `IDisposable` interface (yes, obviously you can name a method `Dispose` without implementing `IDisposable`, *don't do that!*).

However, calling it manually is *sometimes* a code smell, smell of code that *should probably* be using `using` instead. By "manually" here I mean calling `Dispose` outside of the implementation of another `Dispose`.

Calling it twice should also be safe and is [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx):

> If an object's Dispose method is called more than once, the object must ignore all calls after the first one. **The object must not throw an exception if its Dispose method is called multiple times.** Instance methods other than Dispose can throw an ObjectDisposedException when resources are already disposed.

*(my emphasis)*

Should you be calling `Dispose` twice? **No!**. That is also a code smell of code that no longer has control of what it has done and what it has left to do and ends up doing things "just to be sure". *Don't do that either!*

So if you write code correctly, sure you can call `Dispose` manually.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my thoughts. In my specific case I made object state safe, so that `Dispose` can be called multiple times, even from private methods (and because it uses unmanaged resource it **must** be called by the user at least once), yet I was told my object is zombie, I shouldn't do this, blablabla. Therefore a question.

Answer (score 3):

You're right, Dispose is just another method, belonging to IDisposable. It just has the added benefit of being able to be automatically called when a using() scope ends - it is *not* equivalent to a destructor and whoever told you that doesn't truly understand what they're saying.

I'd always use a using() block where possible, but if you're careful you can manually call Dispose instead and it will have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio 2015 offers up (finally) a suggested pattern for implementation of `IDisposable` which matches the guidelines.

This is the stub that VS creates for you when selecting to implement the *disposable* pattern. The TODOs guide us through the implementation.

```
class Disposable : IDisposable
{
    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // TODO: dispose managed state (managed objects).
            }

            // TODO: free unmanaged resources (unmanaged objects) and override a finalizer below.
            // TODO: set large fields to null.

            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    // TODO: override a finalizer only if Dispose(bool disposing) above has code to free unmanaged resources.
    // ~Disposable() {
    //   // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
    //   Dispose(false);
    // }

    // This code added to correctly implement the disposable pattern.
    public void Dispose()
    {
        // Do not change this code. Put cleanup code in Dispose(bool disposing) above.
        Dispose(true);
        // TODO: uncomment the following line if the finalizer is overridden above.
        // GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Note the use of a flag to indicate if the `Dispose` has already been called. This flag can be used to throw `ObjectDisposedException` instances on method calls and properties across the classes implementation.

The intention of `Dispose` has always been to clean up unmanaged resources. However, the syntactic sugar of the `using` keyword (requires an `IDisposable`) lets you create really tidy 'context' pattern classes for managing resource access, even if there are no unmanaged resources used.

As usual, document the usage and the intentions clearly and you can't go wrong but please avoid methods called 'Dispose' if you don't implement the interface.

Comment: What this answer has to do with this question? Question is not how to implement `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a critical difference between `Dispose` in .NET versus destructors in other languages: if one has a pointer to an object in another language and the object is deleted, one will have an *invalid* pointer and there is no way to do anything with it, including determine whether it is still valid, without invoking Undefined Behavior.  By contrast, in .NET if one has a reference to an object which gets `Dispose`d, the reference will continue to be a valid reference to the object in question.  The object will likely refuse to do much because it's been disposed, but such refusal is affirmatively generated by the object itself.  No Undefined Behavior involved.

On the flip side, when a destructor is invoked in other languages like C++ an object can be certain that no valid pointers exist to it anymore, but that is not true of `Dispose`.  Consequently, code should avoid pooling public-facing objects and instead have every request for a new object return a new object (which may be a wrapper to a pooled object).  If no reference to the pooled object exists outside the wrapper, and `Dispose` invalidates that reference before returning the object to the pool, then a future object request can be satisfied by encapsulating the pooled object in a new wrapper which will again hold the only reference to it.

Comment: If we call disposed object a *zombie* (because it's supposed to be dead, but it's not yet as we still have reference) and then there are methods to init and use that object again and again (and call `Dispose` again), then it's totally legit, right? Someone may decide to forget the reference and create a new object. Some other may try to reuse the object (e.g. when initializing new object is expensive) and he should be able to do this. In my opinion only if object explicitly throws `ObjectDisposedException` it's clearly not reusable, otherwise you never know and it is ok for it to be so. Right?

Comment: @Sinatr: See second paragraph.

Comment: I don't understand it. I fail to see anything related to my question or my comment in it.. /confused.. Wrapper? Pooling? Do you have some bigger problem in the mind when someone is abusing `Dispose` or what?

Comment: @Sinatr: I misread your point as being concern that an object might get "reused" by someone other than the original owner, which can be a problem in some scenarios if public-facing objects are pooled.  In general, expecting to reuse objects after `Dispose` is a bad idea, though disposed object may retain enough information to be used as templates for new objects.  If the expensive parts are encapsulated by reference, such an operation may be cheap.